# Loop & append Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array of objects

```
[
  {
    "id": "41796005",
    "name": " Manoj ",
    "phoneno": " xyz",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "160865953",
    "name": " Manisha Sajnani ",
    "phoneno": "xyz",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

This is the `id` div's in the html page

```
<div class="tuple on" data-tuple-id="160865953" ></div>
```

so my question is that how can i append the `id's div` `phoneno` value if both matches

the div's are in the no. of 40

sho how can we loop upon them & append that data to the id which is available in the array

Comment: Use a loop, such as [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), to iterate over each object in your array. Then you can select the `div` by its `data-tupe-id` attribute and set its `text()` to contain the phone number. If you need more specific help, please show the JS you've written so we can help you to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use loop on data, compare id and append your data as html on div.

Example:

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "41796005",
    "name": " Manoj ",
    "phoneno": " xyz",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "160865953",
    "name": " Manisha Sajnani ",
    "phoneno": "xyz",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
  }
]
$('.tuple').each(function() {
  var divid = $(this).data("tuple-id");
  var _id = $(this);
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if (divid == val.id) {
      _id.html(val.name + '---' + val.phoneno + '---'+ val.email)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tuple on" data-tuple-id="160865953"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible recipe.

```js
arr.forEach((x) => {
  const elem = document.querySelector(`[data-tuple-id="${x.id}"]`)
  elem.innerHTML = x.phoneno
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
$(".tuple").text(function() {
  var n = d.find(x => x.id === $(this).attr("data-tuple-id"))

  return n ? n.phoneno : "";
})
```

This will insert the value from `phoneno` into the div if any match is found

**Demo**

```js
var d =  [
  {
    "id": "41796005",
    "name": " Manoj ",
    "phoneno": " test",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "160865953",
    "name": " Manisha Sajnani ",
    "phoneno": "xyz",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
  }
]

$(".tuple").text(function() {
  var n = d.find(x => x.id === $(this).attr("data-tuple-id"))

  return n ? n.phoneno : "";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tuple on" data-tuple-id="160865953" ></div>

<div class="tuple on" data-tuple-id="41796005" ></div>
<div class="tuple on" data-tuple-id="23123123" ></div>
```